# Which is the probability that the ball is white?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We have three boxes A, B, C with 10 balls in each of them.

The first two have 5 white and 5 black balls and C has 8 white and 2 black balls.

We choose arbitrarily one of the pairs $\{A,B\}$ and $\{B,C\}$ and then we choose arbitrarily one of the two boxes of the pair and we pick one ball from that.

Which is the probability that this is white?

$$$$

For that do we consider the conditional probability, i.e. the probability that we pick a white ball given that we have choosen the set $\{A,B\}$ plus the the probability that we pick a white ball given that we have choosen the set $\{B,C\}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional probability, but it would be better to first calculate the probabilites of choosing each box. Because of the grouping of boxes it's not hard to see that $P(A) = P(C) = \frac 14$ and $P(B) = \frac 12$, where $P(X)$ is the probability of choosing box $X$. Then for $P(W)$, the probability of choosing white ball, we have:

$$P(W) = P(A)P(A|W) + P(B)P(B|W) + P(C)P(C|W) $$
$$= \frac 14 \cdot \frac 5{10} + \frac 12 \cdot \frac{5}{10} + \frac 14 \cdot \frac{8}{10} = \frac 18 + \frac 14 + \frac 15 = \frac{5+10+8}{40} = \frac{23}{40}$$

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at your process for choosing a box and compute the chance that you choose each box.  There is an asymmetry because $B$ is part of both pairs.  What is the chance you choose each box?  Since $A$ and $B$ have the same mix of balls all you really care about is the chance you choose $(A or B)$ and the chance you choose $C$.  Now compute the chance you get a white ball given the chances for each kind of box.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The probability that we choose a ball from $C$ is ${1\over2}\cdot{1\over2}={1\over4}$. Therefore the probability $p$ that we obtain a white ball is given by
$${1\over4}\cdot{4\over5}+{3\over4}\cdot{1\over2}={23\over40}\ .$$

Comment: Thank you!! :-)